static forward slashes in datetime field
I have a form with a date and datepicker implementation.  I wish to use the dd/MM/yyyy format, but have the forward slashes present statically.  Currently I have this:
final dateOfBirth = TextEditingController();

...

TextFormField(
controller: dateOfBirth,
keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date of birth', hintText: 'dd/MM/yyyy', hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
onTap: () async {
  await showDatePicker(
      context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(), firstDate: DateTime(1910), lastDate: DateTime.now()
  ).then((selectedDate) {
    if (selectedDate != null) {
      dateOfBirth.text = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(selectedDate);
    }
  });
},
validator: (String? value) {
  if (value!.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please enter your birthdate !';
  }
  if(DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').tryParse(value) == null){
    return 'Please enter a valid date of birth !';
  }
  return null;
})

The hint as a placeholder is a helpful indication and the datepicker will fill it in correctly, but the user can mess up the field afterwards. I want the user to only have to enter the numbers and not deal with the slashes. How do I add the forward slashes visually without it being part of the formfield value?  Then the stored value would become ddMMyyyy format internally, but visually the slashes are still present.
I hope I don't have to create three separate formfields for the date, month and year to achieve this.

I encountered the same problem, and I was able to solve it with the following approach:
Here is the main Date Formatter code,
class CFormatter {
  // Format the date
  static String formatDate(DateTime? date) {
    // Null-aware operator (??=) to handle null values
    date ??= DateTime.now();
    return DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date);
  }
}

class DateController extends GetxController {
  static DateController get instance => Get.find();

  TextEditingController submissionDateController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> pickDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    );

    if (selectedDate != null) {
      String formattedDate = CFormatter.formatDate(selectedDate);
      submissionDateController.text = formattedDate;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    submissionDateController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Here’s how I integrated it into a form field:
Expanded(
  child: CTextFormField(
    label: 'Date',
    prefixIcon: Iconsax.calendar_search,
    onTap: () => date.pickDate(context),
    controller: date.submissionDateController,
    readOnly: true, 
  ),
),

By setting readOnly: true, the user can't manually input or edit the date field, forcing them to use the date picker. This helps prevent accidental formatting issues or user errors in the date input.

I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to be what I am looking for.  This does not display the forward slashes statically.  It just forces the user to use the datepicker, which I can do in my code too by simply adding the readOnly to true.  Personally, I dislike using the datepicker and am faster with just entering the digits in date fields.  That's why I want to provide this option instead of forcing the datepicker.  The app might become available on desktop and browsers later, so the numpad will definitely be faster.
